# Problem with string arrays in C - maybe pointer related? K&R problem 3-2

Tags: c, string

I am working through the K&R C programming language book and have run into a problem. In this code I am attempting to replace newlines and tabs in strings with their C counterparts `'\n'` and `'\t'` respectively. My code performs this function correctly, but also somehow erases the first character from the input string array, even though the string is only used to source char values and is never assigned to.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void escape(char s[], char t[]);

int main(void){
    char t[] = "This is a   string"; // tab in between "a" and "string"
    char s[] = "";
    escape(s, t);
    printf("%s\n", s); // prints "This is a\tstring" as expected
    printf("%s\n", t); // prints "his is a\tstring" with first character removed. Why??  
}


/**
* Copy from t to s while replacing actual tabs and newlines with "\n" and "\t"
* char s[] - the array that is being copied to
* char t[] - the array that is being copied from
*/
void escape(char s[], char t[]){
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    
    while (t[i] != '\0'){
        switch (t[i]){
        case '\n':
            s[j++] = '\\';
            s[j++] = 'n';
            break;
        case '\t':
            s[j++] = '\\';
            s[j++] = 't';
            break;
        default:
            s[j++] = t[i];
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
This is a\tstring
his is a\tstring
```

Comment: `char s[] = "";` declares an array with 1 element, the null terminator. You can't add anything to the array, you'll write outside the array bounds. You need to declare it to be long enough to hold the longest possible result of escaping.

Comment: This array `char s[] = "";` has space for one character, the null byte.  Add anything else to it and you are writing out of bounds.  C does not allocate strings dynamically; you have to control that memory allocation.  `char s[sizeof(t) * 2] = "";` would be safer.

Comment: @John Saylor " char t[] = "This is a   string"; // tab in between "a" and "string""". There is no tab character.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow — that's probably because SO has converted the tab to some number of spaces.  Yes, the tab could sensibly have been represented by `\t` — it would be far safer.  But in the OP's code, it is probable that there really is a tab where they claim there is a tab.

Answer (score 0):

Some minor fixes:

- Since we don't intend to write to `t`, declare it `const char[]` (and it's more idiomatic to write that as `const char*`, so change that too).  More conventional names such as `src` and `dest` will aid comprehension.
- `s` has insufficient space for the output.  Size it to be big enough for the expanded string.  As an upper bound, make it twice as long as the input string; we know the output can't be longer than that.

It turns out that the second of these also fixes your problem - it seems that `t` and `s` are stored close to each other in memory, so writing off the end of `s` has corrupted the value in `t`.

You've actually happened across a serious problem that affects many functions written in C: the caller needs to know how much space to provide for the function to write into.  And when it goes wrong, you get Undefined Behaviour, which is notoriously tricky to diagnose (in the worst cases, you get the behaviour you wanted and expected, right up until the moment you deploy the code to a production system...)

Fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void escape(char *dest, const char *src);

int main(void)
{
    char t[] = "This is a\tstring"; // tab in between "a" and "string"
    char s[sizeof t * 2] = "";
    escape(s, t);
    printf("%s\n", s); // prints "This is a\tstring" as expected
    printf("%s\n", t); // prints "his is a\tstring" with first character removed. Why??  
}


/**
* Copy from src to dest while replacing actual tabs and newlines with "\n" and "\t"
* char dest[] - the array that is being copied to
* char src[] - the array that is being copied from
*/
void escape(char *dest, const char *src) {
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    while (src[i] != '\0') {
        switch (src[i]) {
        case '\n':
            dest[j++] = '\\';
            dest[j++] = 'n';
            break;
        case '\t':
            dest[j++] = '\\';
            dest[j++] = 't';
            break;
        default:
            dest[j++] = src[i];
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

---

I noticed another problem - we don't copy the terminating null character.  We're getting away with this at the moment because our `s` is packed with nulls, so it's not apparent in this simple test.  To fix it, we need to move the test to the end of the loop, after we have copied from the source.  `do`-`while` is ideal for that.

Here's the function rewritten using pointer arithmetic instead of indexing, and with the termination bug fixed:

```
void escape(char *dest, const char *src) {
    do {
        switch (*src) {
        case '\n':
            *dest++ = '\\';
            *dest++ = 'n';
            break;
        case '\t':
            *dest++ = '\\';
            *dest++ = 't';
            break;
        default:
            *dest++ = *src;
            break;
        }
    } while (*src++);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. With pointer arithmetic, does the (*src++) test return false if it encounters the null character? I haven't seen it used before.

Comment: Yes, the null character always evaluates false.